# Usage of a saved dimension in another saved dimension in a \pgfdeclareshape command

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I have a question about `\saveddimen` usage inside of a `\pgfdeclareshape`
command. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}{
   \savedanchor{\centerpoint}{\pgf@x=0pt\pgf@y=0pt}
   \saveddimen{\mydima}{%
      \pgf@x=20pt
   }
   \saveddimen{\mydimb}{%
      \pgf@x=20pt  %% =\mydima
      \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
   }
   %   
   \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
   \backgroundpath{%
        \pgf@xa=\mydima \pgf@ya=\mydima
        \pgf@xb=\mydimb \pgf@yb=\mydimb
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
   }     
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
   \node[myshape,draw] at (2,2) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces a node, with top and bottom horizontal lines.
In my real world example, I want to have a dimension `\dimenb`
which is a function of `\dimena`. If I uncomment the `%%` in the
`\saveddimen{\dimenb}` command the setting `\pgf@x=\dimmena` 
I get an error message.

Question: Is it legal to use a saved dimension in the definition of
another saved dimension, and if yes, how?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Only `\saveddimen{\mydima}{\pgf@x=20pt}\saveddimen{\mydimb}{\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}` would be enough. Since `\pgf@x` is overwritten by `\mydima` previously.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! You tell me (correct?)
that I should use the fact that after defining `\mydima` the register `\pgf@x`
still holds the dimension, and I can use it in the definition of `\mydimb`.
That is easily breakable code. Add additional code bewtween the statements to break it
       \saveddimen{\mydima}{ --set \pgf@x here}
       \some-code-manipulating \pgf@x
       \saveddimen{\mydimb}{ --\pgf@x here is no longer set to \mydima}
I still wonder why I cannot
use the `\mydima` macro in another `\saveddimen` command, as it works in the
`\backgroundpath` ?

Comment: @BertfriedFauser I'm really sorry for the delay. If you want to ping someone in the comments you can put an `@` character and the nickname just as I did in this comment. There is even an autocomplete feature if you type a few characters and press TAB key. I will try to address your question as soon as possible.

Comment: @percusse No worries, I see your answer `works' for me, so I am not stuck. As I am new to stack exchange, I'll need to learn how it properly works :-\

Answer (score 5):

In the comments, percusse suggests writing:

```
\saveddimen{\mydima}{\pgf@x=20pt}
\saveddimen{\mydimb}{\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
```

To see why this works, we need to trace through the definitions.  Within `\pgfdeclareshape` then `\saveddimen` is actually `\pgf@sh@saveddimen` whose definition is:

```
\def\pgf@sh@saveddimen#1#2{%
  \expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\csname pgf@sh@s@\shape@name\endcsname{\pgf@sh@resaveddimen{#1}{#2}}}
```

So when the shape is declared, we see that `\pgf@sh@s@<shapename>` gains the command `\pgf@sh@resaveddimen{#1}{#2}`.  Presumably, the macro `\pgf@sh@s@<shapename>` is run when the shape is used to set all the dimensions and so forth.  So to find out what happens when it is run, we need to look at `\pgf@sh@resaveddimen`.  This is:

```
\def\pgf@sh@resaveddimen#1#2{%
  {#2\global\pgf@x=\pgf@x}%
  \edef\pgf@sh@marshal{%
    \noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\pgf@sh@savedpoints{%
      \noexpand\def\noexpand#1{\the\pgf@x}%
    }}%
  \pgf@sh@marshal%
}
```

So `#2` (which was the execution code) gets run, then `\pgf@x` gets set to a **global** version of itself (this is important).  Now this *doesn't* get saved as the given name, but the code `\def\<given name>{<the actual value of \pgf@x>}` gets saved to `\pgf@sh@savedpoints`.  Note that this is the *actual* value, not the macro `\pgf@x`.

We have three stages, therefore: *declaration* when the template is set up, *definition* where a shape is defined, and *use* where the various parts are used (parts of which are in the *definition* stage, so this can get confusing).

Let's trace this through with the above code, and its variations.

1. **Declaration**.  So here we run the `\saveddimen` commands which do the code appendages.  At the end of this, `\pgf@sh@s@myshape` has (in addition to whatever else it has):

   ```
   \pgf@sh@resaveddimen{\mydima}{\pgf@x=20pt}
   \pgf@sh@resaveddimen{\mydimb}{\pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
   ```
2. **Definition**.  Now `\pgf@sh@s@myshape` is run.  This executes the above two commands (amongst other things).  After the first is run, the state of play is the following: `\pgf@x` is **globally** set to `20pt` and `\pgf@sh@savedpoints` has `\def\mydima{20pt}` in it.  The first of these is the reason why we can use `\pgf@x` in the definition of `\mydimb`.  The second is the reason why we cannot use `mydima`.

   Then at the end, `\pgf@sh@savedpoints` contains `\def\mydima{20pt}\def\mydimb{-20pt}`.
3. **Use**.  This is where `\pgf@sh@savedpoints` is executed and all the macros are finally defined.  So everything is set up *before* the assignments are made.

In conclusion, `\mydima` is not available when the code for `\mydimb` is set up but so long as they are declared one after the other then when the definition code for `\mydimb` is executed then the value of `\pgf@x` is whatever `\mydima` would have been set to.

Comment: Wow, TeXbook explanation compared to my saved (and forgotten again!) draft.

Comment: @AndrewStacy Great explanation, that helps a lot to understand whats going on.

Comment: @percusse Thanks.  I was a bit worried I might be stepping on toes, but decided from the timings that it was okay.  Bertfried: Your question, and percusse's solution, piqued my curiosity!  I hate not understanding something.

Comment: No worries, that can never happen. At most, a bad joke would follow :)