# How to declare new path commands in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, pgf-core

The TikZ Manual, section 59.5 and [some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/creating-node-shapes) [very good](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65690/custom-shapes-in-tikz) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18400/can-a-shape-be-composed-out-of-subshapes-in-tikz) [on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65642/use-a-custom-shape-as-a-building-block) explain how to declare new shapes for TikZ *nodes* with `\pgfdeclareshape{myshape} ...` to later use them with

```
\node[shape=myshape] (name) {text};
```

But is it also possible to create a new shape to place on a path, which would then be used like this?

```
\draw (0,0) myshape (5, 7);
```

How can one declare a new path command?

Comment: adding commands like that you need to alter the sequence of interpretation in `tikz`. That I would not recommend, but what is wrong with: `\draw (0,0) (name) (5,7)`? By the way, `shape=myshape` does not give the shape a name, I suppose you mean `name` instead of `myshape`?

Comment: @zeroth: `shape=myshape` is the usage I intended assuming that it was defined somewhere with `\pgfdeclareshape{myshape}...`

Comment: @Jake: The duplicate is correct, this answers my question.